# Issue while building Cocoa/X Code modules using Flutter in VS Code

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, visual-studio-code, cocoa

I'm having an issue while running an app with Flutter in VS Code, using X Code's macOS desktop or iOS simulator (with conda env).

- Macbook Air mid 2021 (M1), Monterey 12.6
- Visual Studio Code 1.76.0
- Flutter 3.7.6
- X Code 14.2
- Cocoa Pods 1.5.2

I get a extremely huge debug console error list, and each error section start with differents modules but similar messages. For example:

```
While building module 'Cocoa' imported from /Users/......./macos/Pods/Target Support Files/FMDB/FMDB-prefix.pch:2:
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Headers/Cocoa.h:12:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSBundle.h:6:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.s
```

and then

```
(...)
error: function does not return string type - (nullable instancetype)initWithUTF8String:(const char *)nullTerminatedCString NS_FORMAT_ARGUMENT(1);
```

or

```
(...)
 error: function does not return NSString - (instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)aString NS_FORMAT_ARGUMENT(1);
```

This pattern repeat for a lot of times, where different modules are called: *Cocoa, Foundation, AppKit, ApplicationService, CoreData, CoreLocation, CoreImage, CoreVideo, CloudKit, IOSurface, Metal, and QuartzCore*.
At the bottom, the following error is presented:

```
warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Flutter Assemble' from project 'Runner')
```

What could be the origing of the issue? I re-installed basically everything: X Code plenty of times and Cocoa Pods; I've done a `flutter clean` (with a following `flutter pub get`). This issue arises after updating the last version of X Code, but even with and older version, same errors occured.

What is this mess?

Comment: have you tried clearing your Xcode cache? Related: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/113261 and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/116322

Comment: What does flutter doc say?

Comment: @returnVoid do you meant the `flutter doctor` command? If so, it might be better to say the full thing to avoid confusion with people new to the technology.

Comment: @returnVoid flutter doctor returned just an issue with Android Studio ("Android Studio not found at androidstudiofolder/Contents")

Comment: @user I tried to use a different Toolchain with the latest Swift and also to clear the cache, but nothing changed.